# Can I use slerp multiple times to average quaternions?

Tags: quaternions

As I understand slerp interpolates between two quaternions and returns an unit quaternion. So if I want to average 3 quaternions could I do(Assuming they all are close to each other):

```
Eigen::Quaterniond t4;
Eigen::Quaterniond u4;
Eigen::Quaterniond v4;
Eigen::Quaterniond average1 = t4.slerp(0.5, u4);
Eigen::Quaterniond average2 = average1.slerp(0.5, v4);
```

Intuitively it makes sense to me, but then again its quaternions we're talking about.

Comment: Yes you can. But be carefull to used weights . Provided code average rotations with weights 
t4 - 0.25
u4 - 0.25
v4 - 0.5

Comment: I don't understand your comment, looking at the formula on wikipedia it seems that t 0.5 would interpolate the middle back, right?

Comment: assume 3 values a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3, 

lets average it  (1+2+3)/3 = 2
but 

t1 = a1*0.5 +a2*0.5 = 1*0.5 + 2*0.5 = 1.5
result = t1*.05 + a3*0.5 = 1.5*0.5 + 3*0.5 = 1.25 + 1.5 = 2.75

Comment: Now I see your point, but this is not a big problem if all 3 are close to each other, right? Or how would I go about finding better weights?

Comment: It can change interpolated trajectory and speed of interpolated object (in saddle points). 

For quaternions that are close , can be used linear interpolation LERP.  Don't forget to flip signs of lerped quaternions , if their dot product negative.

And use normalization after LERP